# Sentiment Analysis for Q&A based reviews

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I'm a self-learning ML enthusiast and I recently started learning NLP and performing Sentiment Analysis on imdb, yelp, amazon datasets(using Python). I came across a dataset where the reviews were in the form of Q&A's for each product. 
1) What do you like about the product?
2) What do you dislike about the product?
3) What would you recommend to improve?
4) What did you use this product for?

I was wondering if Sentiment Analysis can be performed on this type of data or not? If yes, any tips/pointers/links to reading material in the right direction would be much appreciated. Also, there was no overall rating given for the product, so I stuck on that aspect as well.

-Luc.

Comment: For sentiment analysis, we only require the user's answers and not the questions. So, extract the answers and try your model on them.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Thanks for the tip. Making some progress now.